# Content Delivery 2011 SP1 architecture understanding

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are upgrading from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1. We are done with Tridion Content Manager Server installation. We want to understand detail architecture on Content delivery server.

1. What is the difference between content delivery server and presentation server?
2. We have lot of Dynamic Component presentations as well as Embedded component presentations, exactly where we have to do changes in cd_storage_conf so that embedded presentations along with page will go in application folder (.net application) and Dynamic component presentations will go to SQL database? (in Tridion 5.3 there was a element in config file called “DefaultRootLocation”
3. While doing installation of Content Delivery we installed it on D:\Tridion.  After installation we can see subfolders like bin,cofig,incoming,lib, log, uninstaller etc. Our .Net application will be sitting on D:\inetpupp\.  Do we need to copy or change any folder, dll, config file to our .net application folder?
4. Where we can find some diagram, or architecture against which we can validate our installation?

Comment: What configuration do you currently have for #2? Don't put it in a comment please, just update the question with ***the relevant fragment***.

Comment: When you say configuration what exactly you are looking for ? Should I update on <Bindings>, <CacheBindings> section ?

Comment: I would also recommend a delta training so you can think better design choices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## What is the difference between Content Delivery server and presentation server?

Content Delivery is a set of modules from Tridion that you install on your presentation server. So we typically talk about Tridion Content Delivery and user145602's presentation server.

## Do we need to copy or change any folder, dll, config file to our .net application folder?

Yes, you will indeed need to copy the relevant files (JARs, DLLs and _config.xml's) to your web site under `c:\inetpub` (or wherever you have pointed IIS to).

Exactly what to copy is documented extensively in the online documentation (log on required): 
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_DFE30215E62D42D097516F0450C853D7

Typically:

1. the DLLs go into the `bin` folder of your web site (unless noted otherwise)
2. the JARs go into a `lib` folder ***under*** the `bin` folder of your web site
3. the _config.xml files go into a `config` folder ***under*** the `bin` folder of your web site

## Where we can find some diagram against which we can validate our installation?

The (online) documentation is full of architecture diagrams, such as this one (log on required): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C72D061178C64B88A93134DE051A082C

But how directly applicable those are to your installation depends on many factors beyond anyone's control but you (or the people that set up and upgraded this system for you). If you want to validate your installation, I'd suggest getting an experienced consultant from SDL or one of our partners to walk through it with you.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that was quite informative.
What I also wanted to know was answer to point number 2 mentioned by user1453602.

Answer (score 2):

I got this information regarding your query in point no. 2:

To enable storage of content on the local file system, ensure the
presence of the following  element, uncommented:

```
**<Storage Type="filesystem" Id="LocalFileSystem_01" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true"
Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory">
<Root Path="STORAGE_PATH" />
</Storage>**
```

where STORAGE_PATH is the fully qualified path to the root folder of
your storage location.